# Java - Why am I getting this variety of errors?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class enrollment {
static String sName;
static int sAge;
static int sID;
static String sAddress;
static String sGender;

enrollment(String sName, int sAge, int sID, String sAddress, String sGender){
    this.sName=sName;
    this.sAge=sAge;
    this.sID=sID;
    this.sAddress=sAddress;
    this.sGender=sGender;
}

public String getSName() {
    return sName;
}

public int getSAge() {
    return sAge;
}

public int getSID() {
    return sID;
}

public String getSAddress() {
    return sAddress;
}

public String getGender() {
    return sGender;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<enrollment> studentData = new LinkedList<enrollment>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter student name");
    sName = input.nextLine();
    studentData.add(sName);

    System.out.println("Enter student age");
    sAge = input.nextInt();
    studentData.add(sAge);

    System.out.println("Enter student ID");
    sID = input.nextInt();
    studentData.add(sID);

    System.out.println("Enter student address");
    sAddress = input.nextLine();
    studentData.add(sAddress);

    System.out.println("Enter student gender");
    sGender = input.nextLine();
    studentData.add(sGender);

    System.out.println(studentData);

    }
}
```

I am trying to make an enrollment program for a school project that takes a persons name, age, ID number, address and gender and then print it all out after the user inputs all the information that is asked. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I feel like I have done everything correctly. I'm not sure on what I can do to fix these errors. What is causing these errors and how can I fix them?

Errors given are

```
The method add(enrollment) in the type LinkedList<enrollment> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
The method add(int, enrollment) in the type LinkedList<enrollment> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
The method add(int, enrollment) in the type LinkedList<enrollment> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
The method add(enrollment) in the type LinkedList<enrollment> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
The method add(enrollment) in the type LinkedList<enrollment> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

at enrollment.main(enrollment.java:44)
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? Your `add()` calls make no sense.

Comment: This message means: you can't call add() with a String as parameter, since it's a List<enrollment>, and its add() method thus expects an enrollment as parameter. You can only put eggs in a egg box. Not peas or beans.

Comment: Because you define your list to be a list of ``enrollment`` objects. Then you try to add other objects (which are not ``enrollment``s) to that list.

Comment: I'm trying to add the user input into the linked list and then print out the linked list in the end.

Comment: You have to create a new enrollment object and then add it to your list.

Comment: Your code says "Make me a container to hold enrollment - now put a String and an int in there". Very similar to "Make me a box to hold apples - now put a car in there".

Comment: I downvoted because the error message is quite clear as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler says you that you cannot put strings and integers to a list of `enrollment`s. You probably need to create an `enrollment` instance and add it to your list:

```
System.out.println("Enter student name");
sName = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter student age");
sAge = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter student ID");
sID = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter student address");
sAddress = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter student gender");
sGender = input.nextLine();

enrollment en = new enrollment(sName, sAge, sID, sAddress, sGender);

studentData.add(sGender);
```

By the way, you are violating Java standard naming convention: namely, class names should start with a capital letter, so it's better to use `Enrollment` instead of `enrollment` as a class name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create enrollment object first like

```
Enrollment enrollment = new Enrollment(" all the contstructor values here");
```

then set the add it to list

```
studentData.add(enrollment);
```

Or create setter

```
Enrollment enrollment = new Enrollment();
enrollment.setSName(input.nextLine());
```

then finally

```
studentData.add(enrollment);
```